# Excel xls to SQL

Tags: c#

I use Windows Application to develop this solution.
This is my condition：I have an EXCEL xls file that is exported from another company’s system. I want to import it into our database.
I use NPOI to get this EXCEL xls file and successfully written to the database.
But I don't know how to use loops to get the values of this EXCEL xls file , because
the Case Info maybe one record , maybe multiple record.
[This is the EXCEL file.](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjR9QFLQSFGLhi-sc9epG2CU07lm)

```
using NLog;
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Excel_to_SQL
{
    public partial class Excel_to_SQL : Form
    {
        public Excel_to_SQL()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private readonly static NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        private void Excel_to_SQL_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HSSFWorkbook workbook;
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"c:\CaseInfo.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
            }

            ISheet sheet = workbook.GetSheet("CaseInfo");   //read CaseInfo workbook

            if (sheet.GetRow(1).GetCell(1).StringCellValue != null) //null is when the row only contains empty cells 
            {
                using (SqlConnection SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=testsvr;Initial Catalog=test;Trusted_Connection=true")) //test machine connection string
                {
                    string strSQL = null;

                    strSQL = @"insert into \[test\].\[dbo\].\[CaseInfo\] (CaseNo,Customer,DisassembleType,ProjectNo,DispatchedVendor,
                                            AuthStoreNo,AuthStoreName,AuthStoreArea,AuthStoreContact,AuthStoreContactCell,
                                            BusinessTime,BusinessAddress,ContractAddress,PDQType,DualModuleMode,
                                            ECRConn,ConnType,LOGO,ElectronicInvoice,Broadband,
                                            AddInstructions,RequireNo,ContractNo,DTID,ProjectName,
                                            DispatchedDept,OldAuthStoreNo,Header,AuthStoreContactTEL1,InstalledContact,
                                            AOPersonnel,InstalledAddress,ContractPersonnel,SoftwareVer,Peripherals1,
                                            ) values "
                        + '(' + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(1).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(2).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(3).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(4).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(5).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(6).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(7).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(8).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(9).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(10).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(11).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(12).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(13).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(14).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(15).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(16).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(17).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(18).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(19).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(20).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(21).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(1).GetCell(3).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(2).GetCell(3).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(3).GetCell(3).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(4).GetCell(3).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(5).GetCell(3).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(6).GetCell(3).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                        + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(7).GetCell(3).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ')';

                    Logger.Debug(strSQL);

                    //SQL Connection & Command
                    using (SqlCommand SqlCommand = SqlConnection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        SqlTransaction SqlTransaction;

                        // SqlConnection MsDBConnection = new SqlConnection();
                        // MsDBConnection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings\[GetConnectString(ms_conn_type) + GetUserInfo("connection")\].ConnectionString;
                        SqlConnection.Open();
                        SqlTransaction = SqlConnection.BeginTransaction("SqlTransaction");
                        SqlCommand.Connection = SqlConnection;
                        SqlCommand.Transaction = SqlTransaction;
                        try
                        {
                            SqlCommand.CommandText = strSQL;
                            SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            SqlTransaction.Commit();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            if (SqlTransaction.Connection != null)
                            {
                                SqlTransaction.Rollback();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is each case record 22 lines in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your while loop like this, it will increment to a new case each iteration.

```
var row = 1;
var value = sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(1).StringCellValue != null)

while (value!= null)
{
   string strSQL = null;

                strSQL = @"insert into \[test\].\[dbo\].\[CaseInfo\] (CaseNo,Customer,DisassembleType,ProjectNo,DispatchedVendor,
                                        AuthStoreNo,AuthStoreName,AuthStoreArea,AuthStoreContact,AuthStoreContactCell,
                                        BusinessTime,BusinessAddress,ContractAddress,PDQType,DualModuleMode,
                                        ECRConn,ConnType,LOGO,ElectronicInvoice,Broadband,
                                        AddInstructions,RequireNo,ContractNo,DTID,ProjectName,
                                        DispatchedDept,OldAuthStoreNo,Header,AuthStoreContactTEL1,InstalledContact,
                                        AOPersonnel,InstalledAddress,ContractPersonnel,SoftwareVer,Peripherals1,
                                        ) values "
                    + '(' + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
                    + "'" + string.Format(sheet.GetRow(row+1).GetCell(1).StringCellValue.Trim()) + "'" + ','
etc...


        //put this at the end of the loop
        row += 22;
        value = sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(1).StringCellValue != null);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, our assistant give me the newest EXCEL xls file , each case record 43 lines.

Comment: So you change the row variable to increment by the new number - the concept is the same!

Comment: example: row += 43;

Comment: Thanks,last question is how do I input the value in strSQL this string?

Comment: Not sure what this means "Is that StringCellValue can read multiple line in one cell ?"

Comment: I means the EXCEL xls file has line break.

Comment: The text in the cell has a line break?

Comment: In this EXCEL xls file , there are two cells have line break.

Comment: Sorry I know nothing about NPOI and how to handle line breaks. You should ask another question

Comment: Thanks, I try NPOI can get the value if line breaks.
But how do I get the next column's value?

Comment: I guess I really don't understand what you are getting at. If this doesn't help please ask a new question. Just increment the number in GetCell sheet.GetRow(row+1).GetCell(2)